# General element of the inverse of a 4 by 4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider the $4\times 4$ matrix $M$ whose general element $\mu\nu$ is given by
$$
M_{\mu\nu} = -2 b_1\delta_{\mu 1} \delta_{\nu 1} + \delta_{\nu\{\lambda}b_\lambda \delta_{\mu\}1}
$$

$\mu$ and $\nu$ take the values $1,2,3,4$, so for example $b$ is a 4-component vector. Curly braces denote a sum over even permutations of the indices, e.g. $A_{\{\mu \nu} b_{\rho\}}=A_{\mu\nu}b_\rho + A_{\rho\mu}b_\nu +A_{\nu\rho}b_\mu$. The Einstein summation convention is employed on repeated indices, e.g. $b_\lambda b_\lambda = \sum_{\lambda=1}^4 b_\lambda^2$.

In matrix form,
$$ 
M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 \\ b_2 & b_1 & 0 & 0\\ b_3 & 0 &  b_1 & 0\\ b_4 & 0 & 0 & b_1 \end{array}\right)
$$

The problem is to find an expression for the element $\mu\nu$ of the inverse matrix $M^{-1}$, similar to the expression for $M_{\mu\nu}$:
$$
(M^{-1})_{\mu\nu}=\;?
$$

Comment: It doesn't look like your expression $M_{\mu \nu}$ matches the matrix below.  Even if it does, what role is $b_0$ supposed to play?

Comment: I am sorry, the index 0 should be replaced by 1. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

$$M^{-1}=C\left(\begin{matrix}
        -b_1^2 & b_1b_2 & b_1b_3 & b_1b_4 \\
        b_1b_2 & -b_1^2+b_3^2+b_4^2 & -b_2b_3 & -b_2b_4 \\
        b_1b_3 & -b_2b_3 & -b_1^2+b_2^2+b_4^2 & -b_3b_4\\
        b_1b_4 & -b_2b_4 & -b_3b_4 & -b_1^2+b_2^2+b_3^2
        \end{matrix}
\right) $$
Where
$$C=(-b_1^3+b_1b_2^2+b_1b_3^2+b_1b_4^2)^{-1}$$

I didn't do anything fancy, just a straight-forward calculation:

Comment: Ok, but the question is whether it is possible to write its general element more compactly, as some contraction of $\delta_{\mu\nu}$s and $b_\mu$s and so on. Just as I wrote $M_{\mu\nu}$.